# Creating parent and child elements wit Js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm beginner at js/jquery.
I want to code this structure with js/jquery:

```
<div class="box">
    <p>1</p>
    <div class="content"><span>Lorem</span></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <p>2</p>
    <div class="content"><span>Ipsum</span></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <p>3</p>
    <div class="content"><span>Dolor</span></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <p>4</p>
    <div class="content"><span>Sit</span></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <p>5</p>
    <div class="content"><span>Amet</span></div>
</div>
```

I have this code:

```
function addDivs(n) {

    for(var i=1; i<=n; i++) {

        var parentP = $("<p>"+i+"</p>");
        var parentContent = $("<div class='content'></div>");

        var boxClassDiv = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(boxClassDiv);
        boxClassDiv.setAttribute("class", "box");
        $("body").prepend(boxClassDiv, [parentP, parentContent]);
        }
    }

    window.onload = function getFuncs() {
        addDivs(16);
    }
```

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ds6wj38k/2/

I found a few similar questions like this and tried to add to my code but i can't adjust.

Thanks.

Comment: When using jQuery, try to stick to jQuery functions. So no `document.createElement` or `appendChild`. There are jQuery functions for that.

Comment: thanks for your advice, i will try to code more with jquery.

Comment: Something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/ds6wj38k/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all you need a `div` with class `box`:

```
var box = $('<div>').addClass('box');
```

Then you want a `p` with a number:

```
var p = $('<p>').text(1);
```

And finally a `div` with class `content` and `span` inside:

```
var content = $('<div>').addClass('content');
var span = $('<span>').text('any');
content.append(span);
```

So you created elements you need. Time to combine them:

```
var listItem = box.append(p).append(content);
```

And add to `body`!

```
$('body').append(listItem);
```

The final code:

```
function addDivs(n) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var box = $('<div>').addClass('box');
    var p = $('<p>').text(i);

    var content = $('<div>').addClass('content');
    var span = $('<span>').text('any');
    content.append(span);

    var listItem = box.append(p).append(content);

    $('body').append(listItem);
  }
}

window.onload = function getFuncs() {
  addDivs(16);
}
```

**Check out code online:** http://jsbin.com/xeyugubefu/edit?js,output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would suggest to do it:

```
function addDivs(words) {
    words.forEach( function (word, i) {
        $('body')
            .append($('<div>').addClass('box')
                .append($('<p>').text(i+1))
                .append($("<div>").addClass('content').append($('<span>').text(words[i]))));
    });
};

$(function getFuncs() {
    var words = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'.split(' ');
    addDivs(words);
});
```

jQuery is designed to support method chaining, which the above code demonstrates.

Note that apart from building the content with jQuery, you should also replace `window.onload` with a `jQuery.ready` call, which you can write as `$(callback)`.